# Is it possible to see upload percentage in Firefox Quantum

Tags: firefox-addon

The title says it all. When I upload a file in Firefox Quantum, I have no idea how far along the upload is. Is there a way to do this? I know there is an add-on Upload Progress but it's not compatible with Quantum.